# OleDbConnection.Open() hangs

Tags: c#, ms-access, freeze, oledbconnection

We have a windows service written in c# .net 3.5 and it reads/writes to an access db.

We were careful to put all 'new OleDbConnection()' instances in a 'using' clause and similarly make sure OleDBCommand's are disposed.

Yet on one customer's server we found that connection.Open() hangs for over 5 minutes, and we know from the log that it happens at

```
System.Data.Common.UnsafeNativeMethods.IDBInitializeInitialize.Invoke(IntPtr pThis
```

We know of two occurences of the problem on that machine, and in both cases there are more
than one thread simultaneously hanging at that location. In one case two out of the 3 threads
in question reach the Open() call at an 8 seconds difference. Possibly the third thread reaches the call simultaneously with one of the others, I don't know.
Could the fact that more than one thread tries to open a connection at the same time be
the cause for the problem or is it something else?

Thanks, 
Lior

Comment: Do all threads use the same connection settings?